# How to create BelongTo relationship in gorm (GoLang)

Tags: go, go-gorm, belongs-to

Here is my Struct

```
type Book struct {
    ID        uint `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Yearmonth      string `json:"yearmonth"`
    Realname      string `json:"real_name"`
    LanguageId int
    Language   Language
}
```

and here is my Controller Logic

```
func GetBooks(c *gin.Context)  {
  db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)

  var language []models.Language
  if err := db.Where("id=?", c.Param("language_id")).First(&language).Error;

  err != nil {
      c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"data": "No Records Found"})
      return
  }

  var books []models.Book
  if errBooks := db.Where("language_id=?", c.Param("language_id")).Find(&books).Error;

  errBooks != nil {
      c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"data": "No Books Found"})
      return
  }

  c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": books})
}
```

I tried in a couple of ways somehow I'm getting empty data as result. Any suggestions or help that would great. TIA

Comment: Can you show me the routes code and URL your trying to call the API ?

Comment: ```r.GET("/getBooks", controllers.GetBooks)```

Comment: ```http://localhost:8080/getBooks?language_id=1```
I was passing like this I'm getting empty data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `language_id` is not parsed from URL.
[.Param()](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Param) used to get parameter in path. Ex:

```
router.GET("/user/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
    // a GET request to /user/john
    id := c.Param("id") // id == "john"
})
```

But you are not specify any path param. You are passing `language_id` as query param in URL. So, to get querystring parameters you need to use [.Query()](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Query). Ex:

```
GET /path?id=1234&name=Manu&value=
   c.Query("id") == "1234"
   c.Query("name") == "Manu"
   c.Query("value") == ""
   c.Query("wtf") == ""
```

So, use `c.Query("language_id")` instead of `c.Param("language_id")`

```
db.Where("id=?", c.Query("language_id")).First(&language)
db.Where("language_id=?", c.Query("language_id")).Find(&books)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. but getting empty object for Language in Book Response. How to get Language Object along with Book Object? i.e. ``` "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "yearmonth": "2000_07",
            "real_name": "",
            "LanguageId": 1,
            "Language": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "",
                "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
        },```

Comment: @deepu as you already fetched language already you can set in every book or you can preload language also like `db.Where("language_id=?", c.Query("language_id")).Preload("Language").Find(&books)` detail [here](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)

Comment: I did. Marked as a Right Answer. :)

Comment: quick question I would like to use one STRUCT for multiple requests like for above STRUCT ```/books``` I don't wanna display relationship `language` object. but for ```/getBooks``` request I wanna display `language` object. how can i achieve this? TIA

Comment: If you don't preload `language` that won't be fetched and display as null in response